# how to add +1 to string in do function in swift for pagination

Tags: ios, swift, string, pagination, tableview

long story short I'm trying to achieve pagination. To do so I need to add "+1" overtime a do function is called (when the `tableview` reaches its last cell) I'm terrible with swift so any help is appreciated  here is the code that I have try.

```
 do {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in

            self.parser = FeedParser(feedURL: kFeedParserExampleFeedSourceURL + "1")
            self.parser?.delegate = self
            self.parser?.parse()}
```

the url is structured like so:
kFeedParserExampleFeedSourceURL = "http://thestreetlede.com/feed?paged="

in short i need the url parsed to come out like this
http://thestreetlede.com/feed?paged=1
http://thestreetlede.com/feed?paged=2

http://thestreetlede.com/feed?paged=3 
and so on
any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
self.parser = FeedParser(feedURL: "\(kFeedParserExampleFeedSourceURL)1")
```

If kFeedParserExampleFeedSourceURL is optional you might have to force unwrap it

```
 self.parser = FeedParser(feedURL: "\(kFeedParserExampleFeedSourceURL!)1")
```

Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try like this, Change your constant `kFeedParserExampleFeedSourceURL` like this

```
let kFeedParserExampleFeedSourceURL = "http://thestreetlede.com/feed?paged=%d"
```

Now access it like

```
var pageNo = 0
self.parser = FeedParser(feedURL: String(format: kFeedParserExampleFeedSourceURL, pageNo))
```

Now just increment the `pageNo` to change page.

Comment: Have you try my solution?